# Page_Load fires infinity times

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iframe

I have problem with my iframe asp.net page. 
Browser url containst parameter which I need to use in my iframe page.
Obviously I can't get access via .NET so I came up with the idea that at the end of the Page_Load method add sth like that :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bool isReloaded = Request.QueryString.GetValue<bool>("reloaded");
            ContentId = Request.QueryString.GetValue<int>("contentId"); //I need this value
            if (!isReloaded)
            {
                StringBuilder js = new StringBuilder("<script language='javascript'>");
                js.Append("var last = window.top.location.href.substring(window.top.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, window.top.location.href.length); ");
                js.Append("window.location.href = window.location.href + '?reloaded=true&contentId=' + last;");
                js.Append("if(window.location.href.indexOf('reloaded=true') == -1) window.location.reload();");
                js.Append("<" + "/script>");
                Response.Write(js.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

In shortcut I use Javascript to get value I need and fire reload() but with changed QueryString.

Page_Load is firing again and now I have bool isReloaded filled with true.
The condition (!isReloaded) blocks that this time javascript will not be added to Response.
I don't know why, but Page_Load fires again, this time without added parameters so it's the same situation as at the beginning and again is adding JS etc.

Result is that Page_load fires endlessly.
What did I do wrong ? What is the reason ?

Comment: what's your original requirement? this looks like it could be a messy solution to an easy problem.

Comment: I know it's look messy, but I'm using Umbraco in some bigger project. I was thinking that maybe in parent page I will create dynamically iframe in code behind with this parameter

Comment: @usser3580824 Never heared of Umbraco. Is it something parsing your code ensuring that you solve simple problems in a difficult matter? Are there any reasons for not saying what you're even trying to do? That would make it easier to help you - Apart from that it will always rerun that script since you're not doing postbacks - no actual surprise here.

Comment: Umbraco is CMS for .NET. We are making project using this CMS. It's not related with this specific problem . I'm not sure what do you want to know. In parent page I have contentId in url. I need this value, but in iframe I can't get it using request properties so I'm using Javascript to take it (window.top.location) and then making reload to fire the same event but with modify queryString

Comment: So If I understand correctly this added javascript is in each Response. How can I block this javascript not to fire when isReloaded field = true ?

Comment: i agree with banana's answer. you should avoid manual Response.Write if possible and use scriptmanagers for such tasks. Webforms is messy as it is. Fiddling around manually only makes Webforms behave even more annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a look at your code, you have this line:

```
js.Append("if(window.location.href.indexOf('reloaded=true') == -1) window.location.reload();");
```

you are checking the `location.href` for the 'reloaded' var, but note that your page is reloaded as soon as you change the location, and your script keeps executing before it is done, so it results in reloading of the page over an over again without the query string.

remove this line and it should work fine.

another thing though, i changed your code a little bit to register the script on page instead of response.write it,

it shouldnt make any difference, but if your code still doesnt work then try my version:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bool isReloaded;
        int ContentId;
        bool.TryParse(Request.QueryString["reloaded"],out isReloaded);
        int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["contentId"],out ContentId); //I need this value
        if (!isReloaded)
        {
            StringBuilder js = new StringBuilder();
            js.Append("var last = window.top.location.href.substring(window.top.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, window.top.location.href.length); ");
            js.Append("window.location.href = window.location.href + '?reloaded=true&contentId=' + last;");
            ExecScript(js.ToString());
        }
    }
}
void ExecScript(string script)
{
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
    if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("AttachedScript"))
    {
        page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "AttachedScript", script, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help.
Now I have sth like that and it's ok.

```
StringBuilder js = new StringBuilder("<script language='javascript'>");
js.Append("var last = window.top.location.href.substring(window.top.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, window.top.location.href.length); ");
js.Append("if(window.location.href.indexOf('reloaded=true') == -1) window.location.href = window.location.href + '?reloaded=true&contentId=' + last;");
js.Append("<" + "/script>");
```

I didn't know that editing location executes reload automatically ;)
Thanks again